# Maven Error : Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven-2

I am new to Maven . I am running Maven POM.xml file From Eclipse IDE , There was a error occurred in console , i even tried with mvn install -X , but of no use .

Please see the stack trace

**Failed to execute goal on project bayer-ws: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tataaig:bayer-ws:war:1.0:**

```
Failed to collect dependencies for [com.tataaig:bayer-util:jar:1.0 (compile), com.tataaig:bayer-model:jar:1.0 (compile), com.tataaig:bayer-samples:jar:1.0 (compile), com.tataaig:bayer-mw:jar:1.0 (compile), com.tataaig:bayer-fixml:jar:1.0 (compile), cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3 (runtime), jdom:jdom:jar:1.1 (compile), org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.5 (runtime), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), junit:junit:jar:4.4 (test), org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:2.3 (test), org.easymock:easymock:jar:2.3 (test), org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-http:jar:2.2.1 (compile), org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.2.1 (compile), org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.3.1.4 (test), org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.2 (compile), org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.2 (compile), org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.2 (compile), org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.2 (compile), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14 (runtime), commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (runtime), com.tataaig:middleware:jar:5.0.0 (compile), com.tataaig:PRO:jar:1.0.0 (compile), com.tataaig:legacy.backoffice:jar:1.0.0 (compile), hessian:hessian:jar:3.1.6 (compile), commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1 (runtime), xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2 (compile), bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:140 (runtime), org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.8 (compile), net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.1 (runtime)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:99.1: Could not transfer artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:pom:99.1 from/to maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven/): No connector available to access repository maven-central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven/) of type legacy using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

Anybody please help me , i am badly struck .

Comment: Ensure that you have internet access and that you can access the Maven central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven). Maven tries to download the dependencies from there.

Comment: Thank you very much , when i tried to acess http://repo1.maven.org/maven/ , there is 404 error . so where should i change now ??

Comment: Try to access http://repo1.maven.org/maven/ with your browser. You should get a litte inf text _Browsing for this directory has been disabled._ If that works check if you specified all relevant configurations (e.g. proxy) in your maven `settings.xml` file.

Comment: The answer was manually installing jars filesusing mcn install - path to jar file from the command prompt

Comment: Ooh - if the jars are not located in any central repository you have to provide them yourself. Consider that `mvn install` will only install the artifacts to your local (personal) maven repository. If you want to share your project with others you should consider to use a central repository manager like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/).

Comment: @FrVaBe how can i specify relevant configurations.

Comment: @tuxi You have to edit your maven [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer my questions so that may be useful to others, as i was successful with maven build now . 
For installing Application jar files we must use mvn install -- path to jar file .
Please see the syntax

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
```